# convert XML encoded in Windows-1252 to UTF8 encoding

Tags: iphone, character-encoding

I've been trying to solve the encoding conversion problem without any luck so far. I found many suggestions on Stack Overflow how to tackle the problem like converting the XML string into NSData that uses UTF8 encoding, but the result was the same, my Spanish tildas are presented as weird chars. This is what I am using to grab the xml:

```
//Convert Win 1252 encoding of the string to UTF8
NSString *xmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:chosenDrawRss]     encoding:NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding error:&error];
```

If I call the above method with encoding UTF8 app crushes...

I tried converting the string into NSData using UTF8 and then back to NSString but still I had no luck. I wish I could simply change the XML file encoding but unfortunately that is out of my hands :(

When printed to NSLog everything is presented as it should be whether Im printing the XML string or the NSData created from that string...

BEst regards,
L

**UPDATE**: I haven't found the solution for the encoding mess :(. Since I found out that my Win1252 encoded RSS was also containing some HTML that I wanted to get rid of I wrote a .php script that I am calling from iPhone. This .php script parses the original XML from the remote server. This .php script is in UTF8; does some html cleaning and reorders the XML elements so in my case it made sense doing it is this way. Unfortunately, I still have no clue how to read a win1252 encoded XML and convert it to UTF8 directly from iOS :(((

Comment: Do you need to convert the XML contents to string?

Comment: I would like to keep it as a string because my Touch XML parser works with it that way. This could be changed though, but I would like to avoid the code refactoring...